# Date Time format MM/dd/yyyy, HH:mm:ss a to milliseconds in Flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, flutter-web

I have code like below

```
var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timeStamp);//timeStamp = 1630506255982
var d12 = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy, HH:mm:ss a').format(date); // 12/31/2021, 10:10:10 PM
```

Now I want to convert the d12 string back to timeStamp "1630506255982"

How can I achieve this in flutter code?

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this

```
   var dtime = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy, HH:mm:ss a').parse(d12);

   var inMilliseconds = dtime.millisecondsSinceEpoch
```

Comment: It is giving the result as
2021-09-01 09:24:15.000

Comment: i added how to get milliseconds from date

Answer (score 2):

You have to first call this import:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Then base on your code, you can simply add the function that will convert it back to integer.

```
 var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1630506255982);//timeStamp = 1630506255982
 var d12 = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy, HH:mm:ss a').format(date); // 12/31/2021, 10:10:10 PM

  var _convertedDateBackToInt = (date.toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000).toInt(); /// Converts back the base [DateTime] value to [int].
  print(_convertedDateBackToInt); // 1630506255982
```